# Save JSON outputted from a URL to a file

Tags: java, python, ruby, perl, bash

How would I save JSON outputted by an URL to a file?

e.g from the Twitter search API (this http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi)

Language isn't important.

edit // How would I then append further updates to EOF?

edit 2// Great answers guys really, but I accepted the one I thought was the most elegant.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is easy in any language, but the mechanism varies.  With wget and a shell:

```
wget 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi' -O hi.json
```

To append:

```
wget 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi' -O - >> hi.json
```

With Python:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi', 'hi.json')
```

To append:

```
hi_web = urllib2.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi');
with open('hi.json', 'ab') as hi_file:
  hi_file.write(hi_web.read())
```

Answer (score 8):

In PHP:

```
$outfile= 'result.json';
$url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
if($json) { 
    if(file_put_contents($outfile, $json, FILE_APPEND)) {
      echo "Saved JSON fetched from “{$url}” as “{$outfile}”.";
    }
    else {
      echo "Unable to save JSON to “{$outfile}”.";
    }
}
else {
   echo "Unable to fetch JSON from “{$url}”.";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [CURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

```
curl -d "q=hi" http://search.twitter.com -o file1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the (verbose ;) ) Java variant:

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    input = new URL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi").openStream();
    output = new FileOutputStream("/output.json");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Here you could append further stuff to `output` if necessary.
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

**See also**:

- [Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)
- [Java URLConnection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)
- [How to use URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)

Answer (score 3):

In shell:

```
wget -O output.json 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hi'
```

Comment: Just output to stdout (`-`) and use the append redirection operator (`>>`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
 Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);
 mapper.writeValue(new File("myfile.json"), map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this with PHP and fOpen.

```
<?php
// Define your output file name and your search query
$output = 'result.txt';
$search = 'great';

write_twitter_to_file($output, $search);

/*
 * Writes Json responses from twitter API to a file output.
 * 
 * @param $output: The name of the file that contains the output 
 * @param $search: The search term query to use in the Twitter API
*/

function write_twitter_to_file($output, $search) {
    $search = urlencode($search);
    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' . $search;
    $handle = fopen($url, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            file_put_contents($output, $buffer, FILE_APPEND);
            echo "Output has been saved to file<br/>";
        }

        if (!feof($handle)) {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

}
?>
```