# Save JSON outputed from a URL to a file javascript

Tags: javascript, json, curl

I'm trying to save [JSON database stored in Eventful API](http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?c=music&app_key=API_KEY&page_number=1&date=Future&keywords=Andrea-Bocelli&callback=processJSONP)  locally.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188987/how-to-save-json-data-to-file) ,but how to use `Blob()` in my case?

There is one more [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040904/save-json-outputed-from-a-url-to-a-file) but is for Java and i don't know how to use `wget` in javascript.

Thanks! :)

//Edit 1 I downloaded the file with

```
 wget 'http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?c=music&app_key=API_KEY&page_number=1&date=Future&keywords=Andrea-Bocelli&callback=processJSONP' -O hi.json
```

//Edit 2 This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) not working for me

Comment: var processJSONP = function(x){console.log(x);};
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "URL";
    document.body.appendChild(s);

Comment: First defines the callback function, Then creates a dynamic script element and appends it to body. You have to replace "URL" with your link.
As soon as script tag's content loaded, the callback function will be called.

Answer (score -1):

your link is JSONP , you could see processJSONP with a json parameter inside.

if you put this link in

```
<script src="http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?c=music&app_key=your_key&page_number=1&date=Future&keywords=Andrea-Bocelli&callback=processJSONP">
```

then run it on browser you will get error, because this function is not defined yet.

so you need define a callback function then give a parameter,

```
function processJSONP(json){
     // using your json 
        console.log(json)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the API key! :)

Comment: did not realize the key is in the link , but i think it should be ok

Comment: Ops it's was big mistake.Thank you.